# Python api to delete -- elasticsearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I want to delete a particular '_id' in elasticsearch but its not working using elasticsearch python api client.

```
doc = {'system_caused': 'office', 'division': 'National', 'addt_notes': '', 'pg': '100', 'date': '2016/02/15 08:56',
               'duration': '15 minutes', 'outage_caused': 'Scheduled', 'ticket_num': '1234', 'ticket_type': 'JIRA', 'error_count': '1,000 - 5,000'}
self.es = Elasticsearch(['localhost'], verify_certs=True)

result = self.es.index(index='tickets', doc_type='tickets', body=doc)


doc = {'_id': result['_id']}
result = self.es.delete(
        index='tickets', doc_type='tickets', **doc)
```

The inserts are working fine but the delete is failing.

Here is the error I get -

```
TypeError: delete() got an unexpected keyword argument '_id'
```

Comment: It shouldn't be `id`? 
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/blob/master/elasticsearch/client/__init__.py#l682

Comment: You should pass only doc id instead of doc. See [documentation](http://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.org/en/master/api.html#elasticsearch.Elasticsearch.delete) for allowed arguments

Comment: I don't know your use-case, but I want to mention that delete operations are pretty slow. It is, depending on the case, better to update a document by setting a bool which you filter afterwards in queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the source code the input parameters for `delete` include `id`, but not `_id`. Check out the code [here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-py/blob/master/elasticsearch/client/__init__.py#l682).

Answer (score 1):

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch import helpers
from elasticsearch_dsl import connections
import pandas as pd

# initialize list of lists
data = [['tom', 10, 'NY'], ['nick', 15, 'NY'], ['juli', 14, 'NY'], ['akshay', 30, 'IND'], ['Amit', 14, 'IND']]

# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Age', 'Country'])

from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from elasticsearch import helpers
```

##connection to elastic search cluster

```
es_client = connections.create_connection(hosts=['http://localhost:9200/'])
def doc_generator(df):
    df_iter = df.iterrows()
    for index, document in df_iter:
        yield {
                "_index": 'age_sample',
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_source": document,
            }

helpers.bulk(es_client, doc_generator(df))

from elasticsearch_dsl import Search
s = Search(index='age_sample').query("match", _id='V5A3Y34Bq-Uo6Q7qyfBJ')
response = s.delete()
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer. It would be great if you could explain to us how and why your code solves the OP's problem as code itself is not always easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `**` operator in front of a dict, it expands to keyword arguments. So we can rewrite it as:

```
result = self.es.delete(
    index='tickets', doc_type='tickets',
    _id=result['_id'])
```

Thus you are passing `_id` as one of the keyword parameters. As @Forge said, I assume you meant to use `id` in the `delete` call.